# Can't create External Data Source on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, external-data-source

I have SQL Server 2016 and I'm trying to create an external data source to another database on the same server. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples-sql-server-2016) says that it applies to SQL Server 2016 but the following command fails with error

> Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'

Code:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'master_key';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL cred
WITH
     IDENTITY   = 'test_user'
,    SECRET     = 'test_password'
;

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE TEST
WITH
(
  LOCATION = 'sqlserver://same_sql_server'
, CREDENTIAL = cred
)
```

Comment: `LOCATION` requires an instance name for the SQL Server. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Even if it's the default?

Comment: For future reference, based on the documentation it appears the instance name is optional, even so I tried specifying it but it didn't make a difference.